# Calling a function within a function from outside

Tags: javascript, function, nested

I am having some trouble here trying to call function C from an onClick event on the page.

```js
function leftArrowClicked() {
  functionA(functionC);
}

function functionA() {
  function functionB(w) {
    function functionC() {
      // do stuff
    };
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="dashboard_left_arrow" onclick="leftArrowClicked()">Click</div>
```

But it's of course not working. Currently seeing 'functionC is not defined' in the console. I don't know much about nested functions, hence probably why my method isn't working. Any ideas?

Comment: that is not possible. I am not sure what you are exactly trying to do so hard to give you a solution.

Comment: you need to call functionC within the scope of functionA, the parameter you are passing to functionA is doing absolutely nothing and even if it did, it is not being used at all within functionA. In short, your implementation is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something called [Modular Design Patterns](https://www.sitepoint.com/modular-design-patterns-in-javascript/). It goes something like this -- you can see that functionA is an function that is already invoked, so I can call functionB directly on that because it is returned inside an object. Calling functionC can be done on top of that.

```js
var functionA = (function() {
  function functionB(w) {
    function functionC() {
      // do stuff
      return 'inside functionC';
    }
    return {functionC:functionC};
  }
  return {functionB:functionB};
})();

function leftArrowClicked() {
  console.log(functionA.functionB('').functionC());
}
```

```html
<div id="dashboard_left_arrow" onclick="leftArrowClicked()">Click</div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir.

In the end I changed my approach and used an event listener for the button click, rather than relying on the onClick event bound to the button, but I like your idea and I'll keep it in mind in the future :)